# Об употреблении запятой вместо некоторых союзов ("и", "или", "либо", ...)

Tags: стилистика, семантика, пунктуация

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза, и короля, и даму, и валета." означает указание "Возьми туза, короля, даму и валета.",
- указание "Возьми туза, или короля, или даму, или валета." означает указание "Возьми туза, короля, даму или валета.",
- указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета." означает указание "Возьми туза, короля, даму либо валета.",
- указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета." означает указание "Возьми туза, короля, даму либо валета.",
- указание "Не бери ни туза, ни короля, ни даму, ни валета." означает указание "Не бери туза, короля, даму ни валета."?

Answer (score 1):

Пропуск первого союза не меняет грамматику и семантику предложения, то есть  "Возьми туза, или короля, или даму, или валета " не отличается от "Возьми или туза, или короля, или даму, или валета ".

А вот  команда "Возьми туза, короля, даму или валета" неоднозначна, здесь возможны варианты:1) туз, король,дама; 2)туз, король, валет; 3) валет.

Далее неоднозначность команды  приравнивается исполнителем к ее отсутствию, что и справедливо.